# Nothing happen when I boot Ubuntu 16.04_Live USB (already has Correct checksum)

Tags: boot, usb, bios

I already have Ubuntu inatalled and have made a Ubuntu 16.04_Live USB with Unetbootin. Checksum is all OK. I restart and F12 to open interrupt menu, where I can choose memory device to boot. When I choose USB, the menu goes away for a second. Nothing happens. Then it gets back to the same menu.

Already have Ubuntu inatalled

My machine is Lenovo T440s.

Is there something to do with bios setting, or USB? Thanks.

Comment: You do not say if you have a working Linux system already.If you do, install gparted (sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install gparted).Open gparted from a terminal (sudo gparted).Carefully select the usb drive in the drive dropdown.Right click and select 'manage flags'.Make sure that the 'boot' checkbox is ticked, if not, click it then wait.Reboot the machine and see if it works.

Comment: @linuxbun boot and esp are checked. Doesn't solve the problem